# How to create an image hyperlink element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A hyperlink can be created like this

```
jQuery('<a />', {
                href: val.link_to,
                target: "_blank",
                text: text
            }).appendTo("#epic");
```

We can create an image element like this

```
 var img = $('<img />', {
                class: 'hex',
                src: url,
                alt: alternate
            })
```

Instead of **text** how can I use the **image** created above for hyperlink?

Comment: Note that `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript, and should be quoted or replaced with `className`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the image to the link as soon as you create it

```
var img = $('<img />', {
            class: 'hex',
            src: url,
            alt: alternate
        });

jQuery('<a />', {
            href: val.link_to,
            target: "_blank"              
        }).append(img).appendTo("#epic");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation:

```
$('#epic').append($('<a />', {
                    'href': val.link_to,
                    'target': "_blank"              
                }).append($('<img />', {
                     'class': 'hex',
                     'src': url,
                     'alt': alternate
                     }))
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('<a href="'+val.link_to+'" target="_blank"><img class="hex" src="'+url+'" alt="'+alternate+'" /></a>).appendTo('#epic');`